# Возможно ли в Django Admin Panel динамически брать данные из Choice Field?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Мне нужно получать информацию о расписании (Schedule) из ChoiceField так, чтобы от него можно было передавать данные в Inlines.

В самом Inlines мне нужны только те станции, которые относятся к карте (саму карту я могу получить из объекта расписания). А уже после того как выбрана станция, мне нужно дать только те номера пути (Way Number), которые привязаны к этой станции, которая была выбрана ранее.

Суть вопроса такова - **Как получить данные AdminPanel из ChoiceField динамически?**

[image: by]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй использовать `django_select2` - https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html
Там есть возможность настраивать выдачу для опций селекта в зависимости от значений в других полях. Причем можно настроить как простую выборку из модели по зависимым полям (нужный виджет - `ModelSelect2Widget`), так и самостоятельно написать view, который в качестве доп. параметров будет принимать текущие значения в требуемых тебе полях и ты сам сможешь создать запросы любой сложности, основываясь на полученных данных(нужный виджет - `HeavySelect2Widget`). Единственное ограничение - он автоматически находит и подбрасывает значение полей только внутри одной `html` формы. Но при желании и этот момент можно обойти написав свой `.js` файл для инициализации этих полей.